# Issue with PyCharm, Matplotlib and Anaconda on OS X - figure is all black

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, anaconda

I am using PyCharm Community 4.0.7

I am using Anaconda2 4.0.0

I am using OS X 10.11.4

I have configured PyCharm to use Anaconda in the default settings (and can see the list of modules etc).

When I try a simple test in python console:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

The entire plot window just shows up as a black square. I have been searching around trying to find anyone else with this problem....

BTW - after running the show() command, the interpreter provides the following output to the console:

```
Backend MacOSX is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
```

Answer (score 0):

well...seems like updating to PyCharm 4.5.5 fixed it...